# ServiceLocator has not been initialized; I was trying to retrieve SharpArch.Core.CommonValidator.IValidator

Tags: nhibernate, spring.net

### Server Error in '/' Application.

ServiceLocator has not been initialized; I was trying to retrieve SharpArch.Core.CommonValidator.IValidator 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: ServiceLocator has not been initialized; I was trying to retrieve SharpArch.Core.CommonValidator.IValidator

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[NullReferenceException: ServiceLocator has not been initialized; I was trying to retrieve SharpArch.Core.CommonValidator.IValidator]
   SharpArch.Core.SafeServiceLocator`1.GetService() in C:\MyStuff\Projects\SharpArchGitHub\src\SharpArch\SharpArch.Core\SafeServiceLocator.cs:20
   SharpArch.Core.DomainModel.ValidatableObject.get_Validator() in C:\MyStuff\Projects\SharpArchGitHub\src\SharpArch\SharpArch.Core\DomainModel\ValidatableObject.cs:20
   SharpArch.Core.DomainModel.ValidatableObject.ValidationResults() in C:\MyStuff\Projects\SharpArchGitHub\src\SharpArch\SharpArch.Core\DomainModel\ValidatableObject.cs:15
   SharpArch.Web.ModelBinder.SharpModelBinder.OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) in C:\MyStuff\Projects\SharpArchGitHub\src\SharpArch\SharpArch.Web\ModelBinder\SharpModelBinder.cs:40
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object model) +304
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +772
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +345
   SharpArch.Web.ModelBinder.SharpModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) in C:\MyStuff\Projects\SharpArchGitHub\src\SharpArch\SharpArch.Web\ModelBinder\SharpModelBinder.cs:241
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +219
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +109
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +399
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +126
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext) +151
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) +57
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) +7
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +181
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I've looked at the S#arp Architecture framework, but my guess is that you're missing some initialization routine to set up its IOC container. If I recall correctly, S#arp supports multiple IOC containers, which are wrapped in a ServiceLocator.

Have you tried posting your question on the [S#arp Architecture mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/sharp-architecture?pli=1) as well?